# Alarms and Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I have this Android application for alarm and broadcast but its not working.
I am not getting any notification. So I am not sure if the Alarm is working properly as well.

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".AlarmMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**AlarmMainActivity**

```
public class AlarmMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AlarmMainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_main);

        Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,alertIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final Button alarmButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.alarm_button);

        alarmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Long alertTime = new 
                GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
                Log.i(TAG,"Alarm will be sent at : "+ alertTime.toString());

                AlarmManager am = 
                (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alertTime,pendingIntent );

                Log.i(TAG, "Alarm is now set");
            }
        });
    }//oncreate
}
```

**AlarmReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
    private String msgTitle, msgText, msgTicker;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered AlarmReceiver()");
        msgTitle = "Todays Weather";
        msgText = "Its Sunny and Warm";
        msgTicker="Alert";

        PendingIntent notifyIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, new 
        Intent(context, AlarmMainActivity.class),0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 

        NotificationCompat.Builder(context).
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.weather_image).
        setTicker(msgTicker).
        setContentTitle(msgTitle).
        setContentText(msgText).
        setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND).
        setAutoCancel(true).
        setContentIntent(notifyIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =  (NotificationManager)context.
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
        Log.i(TAG,"Notification Sent");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Boomeran: Explain your problem.

Comment: I am not getting any notification. So I am not sure if the Alarm is working properly as well

Answer (score -1):

Well first thing to do when creating a BroadcastReceiver is to register it!

This can be done statically inside the AndroidManifest.xml inside the      `<application />`
 tag, on the same level as your 
`<activity />` tag is found.

```
<receiver
  android:name="fill.your.package.name.AlarmReceiver">

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="MY_ACTION_STRING" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This can be done runtime also. Perhaps there may be cases when you'll need to dynamically register a Receiver as you don't need one who stays for all the lifetime of your app.

For example in an Activity :

```
BroadcastReceiver myDynamicReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // does things 
        ...
        // maybe when done you won't need it anymore so ..
        unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
}
String MY_STRING_ACTION = "ACTION_FOR_RECEIVER";
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MY_STRING_ACTION);

registerReceiver(myDynamicReceiver, filter);
```

remember you'll have to unregister it, somewhere!

Comment: As I don't feel I've answered with some quick non-explicative answer or just with a link and "look here", I'd like to know what about of the down vote I've received. Leave a feedback when you down vote, so that the user may edit and correct mistakes

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I included the <receiver> tag in the AndroidManifest as you suggested. But its still not working. Not sure why is the receiver not working.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".AlarmMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <receiver android:name="com.thirdlaw.alertalarm.AlarmReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="MY_ACTION_STRING"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: Log file:09-03 12:04:54.121    1058-1058/com.thirdlaw.alertalarm D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-03 12:15:52.711    1058-1058/com.thirdlaw.alertalarm I/AlarmMainActivity﹕ Alarm will be sent at : 1441296957718
09-03 12:15:52.721    1058-1058/com.thirdlaw.alertalarm I/AlarmMainActivity﹕ Alarm is now set

Comment: no more entries in the log file. It looks like the receiver is not working. Can you please help

Comment: First of all, MY_ACTION_STRING should (at least, for how I am used to programming) be a `public static final String`, so that it may be referenced in the AndroidManifest.xml

for example, define in your AlarmReceiver.java

`public static final String MY_ACTION_STRING = "ACTION.STRING.FOR.RECEIVER";`

Comment: You have registered your Receiver to listen for an Intent which is set with "MY_ACTION_STRING" Action. You then are expected to send(create) your Intent with the same Action even if you create it to aim AlarmReceiver.class.

Picking your example 
`Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
alertIntent.setAction(AlarmReceiver.MY_ACTION_STRING);`